# Помогите подключится к ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер

Осваиваю Linux и пытаюсь подключится к серверу. Запускаю ubuntu server через виртуальную машину и пытаюсь подключится к серверу через ubuntu desktop тоже через виртуальную машину.
Пользовался инструкцией https://averagelinuxuser.com/ssh-into-virtualbox/
Но сомневаюсь, что она применима.
На завершающем этапе, когда ввожу ssh -p 2222 sixzerx@localhost
Выдает следующее: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

Поменял port на 22 и о чудо, зашло но если честно - совершенно не понимаю почему.

Comment: Вроде это порт для подключения к SSH по умолчанию

Comment: потому что 22 порт стандартный  из коробки для ssh